# Opensshift application stopped automaticlally with catridge of type DIY

Tags: cloud, openshift

I created a application with cartridge of type : DIY. Deployed a sample play application. It worked for one day then stopped automatically. Checked the logs and no luck.

Any one faced this problem ? Below is the log.

```
[2014-05-07 14:01:26] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-05-07 14:01:26] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-05-07 14:01:26] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=255324 port=8080
127.10.32.1 - - [07/May/2014:14:13:18 EDT] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
127.10.32.1 - - [07/May/2014:14:13:20 EDT] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
[2014-05-07 14:20:24] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2014-05-07 14:20:24] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 0):

Applications on the free tier are automatically idled after 24 hours of no http connections from outside of the OpenShift cluster.  You should only need to make an http call to your application to wake it back up, or visit it with your browser.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried to access it. Actually, I get error (error code 503) "Service Temporarily Unavailable. The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later."

Comment: no its not stops in 24 hours it stops in 1 hours or two

Answer (score 0):

Do a  'rhc  app-restart "app- name"'. Then visit the url at least once in 24 hours to keep the app from sleeping or suspending(503).

Hint hint. 24 hour  'touch' can be done automagically.  I don't want to break any SO or OS rules so can't say. Google is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried restarting the application from command line tool and also from web console. Still no luck.

Comment: In the past I have had to do a 'rhc app-force-stop <appname>' then do a restart.  Try that!  You might get lucky.

Comment: I have created a new play application with following parameters in the conf file openshift.play.params="-DapplyEvolutions.default=true -Xms128M -Xmx1024M". It worked for few days and stopped again, though I keep visiting the site daily. It is really annoying in openshift. Do you suggest any alternatives to host play application ?

Comment: What do your logs say? We need more info. Other than that you my try heroku for hosting.

Comment: No errors in the logs. It is been 5 days since I restarted all the cartridges and application is still up and running. But, I do not know the real reason for application is being stopped. Is heroku better than openshift, in terms of deployment options and pricing ?

Comment: If it has been 5 days and your app is still running maybe openshift had a temporary glitch. It happens. I have not tried heroku yet.

Comment: It is dead now again. This is really frustrating and I will move application out of openshift.

Comment: I can't be sure but it sounds like your app is crashing somewhere. Have your checked ALL logs?  Memory issues?  Other than that I'm out of ideas. You can always file a bug report at openshift bugzilla.

Comment: I checked diy log, play log and MySQL log. They are clean. It happened for "Welcome to Play framework" application too, the basic one when u create a fresh play app.